# Assertion Error while checking if Tree is balanced

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a binary tree and want to check if the tree is balanced. I have the following code:

```
public boolean isBalanced(){
        return balanced(root);
    }

    public boolean balanced(Node current){
        int leftHeight;

        int rightHeight;

        if(current == null){
            return true;
        }
        leftHeight = height(current.left);
        rightHeight = height(current.right);

        if(leftHeight - rightHeight <= 1){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    int height(Node node) 
    { 
        /* base case tree is empty */
        if (node == null) 
            return 0; 

        /* If tree is not empty then height = 1 + max of left 
         height and right heights */
        return 1 + Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right)); 
    }
```

The test is giving the error `java.lang.AssertionError` but not any more details. I can´t figure out where that error is coming from.

Comment: because a tree is not balance only if the height on the right node and on the left node is the same (or differs by 1)

Comment: maybe im wrong or misunderstanding something, but isnt that what "leftHeight -rightHeight <= 1" does?

Comment: no, balanced means the same number on nodes on the right node and on the left node, and each children node have the same hight (or at most left is higher by 1 of the right)

Comment: oh you are right, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), the definition of balanced binary tree is `A balanced binary tree is a binary tree structure in which the left and right subtrees of every node differ in height by no more than 1`.

In your code, you are checking

```
if(leftHeight - rightHeight <= 1){
      return true;
}
```

What if `leftHeight = 0` and `rightHeight=2`? Your code will return true as `(0-2) = -2 and -2 <= 1`. You should check the absolute difference between left subtree height and right subtree height.